# How don't reset data in fields after submit click in the redux form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, redux-form

I would like don't reset data after submit in error case. But my values in fields reset after each submit. How to change form? I use redux form. My form looks like this

```
<form className="login-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitData)}>
 <Field
    type="email"
    className="form-control"
    title="email"
    name="email"
    placeholder="Your email"
    component="input"
    required
  />
    <button type="submit" disabled className="btn bg-indigo btn-block">
      Loading
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: This question is very low quality. Please help us understand it more clearly

Answer (score 0):

Please revise the question, we don't know what are the states the holds the value of every field.

So basically just spread the current value of state upon submitting, example

```
handleSubmit() {

codeThatRunsToRedux();

setState({
  input: ...this.state.input,
  etc: ...this.state.etc,
});

}
```